# How to assign a value to different variables inside a loop in c program

Tags: c

How do i assign a value to a different variable every time the loop activates? I want to change the variable inside a scanf() so that when a new number is assigned to a different variable. Like in:

```
int a,b,c,i;

for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)

{

    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
}
```

The loop asks for numbers 3 times, and i want to enter 1,2, and 3. How can i assign them in a different variable each? Like 1 is assigned to a, b=2, and c=3?

Comment: You will need to use an array instead if you want to keep the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Thats what arrays were made for!

```
int numbers[3];

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&numbers[i]);
}
```

Then your three numbers are available via:

```
numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2]
```

Comment: Almost. C arrays are zero indexed, so it's convention to use `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. Don't add in a dummy slot just to accommodate 1-based indexing. It's wasteful and looks like a bug.

Comment: @tadman and, `numbers[0]` value remain indeterminate.

Comment: @tadman you're right. I kept author's structure, hence the code. I've edited the answer not to confuse anybody.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change variable *names* at run-time, because simply they don't exist at runtime. If the type of inputs are of the same type, say, integer, you can use an array of integers to store multiple inputs.

Sample:

```
int array[3] = {0};

//input

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&(array[i]));
}

//output

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    printf("Number %d is %d", i+1, array[i]);
}
```